# Heat Map of Earthquake by Geocodes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, heatmap, ggmap

I would like to plot the heat of earthquake acceleration at Gilroy California. The following is my data; geocodes of each point is in decimal.

```
    lon          lat            Acc.

-121.5897466    36.98443922 0.308722537
-121.5776472    36.98446622 0.343560598
-121.5657399    36.98449289 0.316238725
-121.5528172    36.98452208 0.289579654
-121.5397651    36.98455121 0.278277577
-121.6022388    36.9957913  0.321904187
-121.5897466    36.99578578 0.346187454
-121.57767    36.99578046   0.323865427
-121.5657514    36.99577518 0.296775313
-121.5528643    36.99576944 0.281054324
-121.5398582    36.99576372 0.270957516
-121.6264404    37.00268339 0.3504049
-121.614493     37.00268494 0.343426824
-121.6022388    37.00268646 0.34803746
-121.5897466    37.00268806 0.316975267
-121.5776805    37.00268967 0.300399358
-121.5657618    37.00269118 0.290519468
-121.5528861    37.0026927  0.27529488
-121.5399123    37.00269441 0.264715439
-121.6264404    37.01301756 0.352218819
-121.614493     37.01301354 0.342255779
-121.6022388    37.01300933 0.333444018
-121.5897466    37.01300512 0.315921346
-121.5777013    37.01300115 0.302762624
-121.5657723    37.01299709 0.291672835
-121.5529293    37.01299261 0.266912813
-121.614493     37.0204378  0.327864875
-121.6022388    37.0204297  0.321358226
-121.5897466    37.0204215  0.305797414
-121.5777125    37.02041366 0.293992548
-121.5657835    37.0204058  0.283948148
-121.614493    37.0299123   0.313950088
-121.6022388    37.02991694 0.303625182
-121.5897466    37.02992166 0.291511686
-121.5777299    37.02992617 0.282628812
-121.5657949    37.02993068 0.271427682
```

The following is my code:

```
    GilroyMap=   qmap(location = c(lon = -121.5837188, lat = 37.007846),zoom=12,color="color",legend="topleft",maptype = "terrain", darken=0.0, extent = "device")
data$C <- cut(data$Acc., breaks=10)

    Q=GilroyMap+stat_density2d(data = data, aes(x = lon, y = lat,fill = Acc. ), colour = NA, alpha = 0.5) +

        scale_fill_distiller(palette =1 , breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
        labs(fill = "") +
        theme_nothing(legend = TRUE) +guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

It does not work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot a heat map on a spatial map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802253/how-to-plot-a-heat-map-on-a-spatial-map)

Comment: duplicate question of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802253/how-to-plot-a-heat-map-on-a-spatial-map OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781650/heatmaps-generation-with-r-php-and-mongodb

Comment: @rafa.pereira  In fact, it is not, that is why it is my problem. In all cases, they consider just lat & long not 3 variables. Then, one cannot use stat_density2d. stat_density2d plots heat map of points, not the 3rd variable.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `ggplot` and `ggmap` packages:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)


gilroy <- get_map(location = 'gilroy', zoom =12) 
ggmap(gilroy)


rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('blue','red'))
mydata$Col <- rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(mydata$Acc.,breaks = 10))]

ggmap(gilroy, extent = "device") + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), colour = mydata$Col, 
      alpha = mydata$Acc., size = 6, shape = 15, data = mydata)
```

This will give us:

[image]

You can also do this using `plotly` package in reference to [Maps in R](https://plot.ly/r/scatter-plots-on-maps/);

```
library(plotly)

g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showland = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
  subunitcolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("gray85"),
  countrywidth = 0.5,
  subunitwidth = 0.5)


p <- plot_geo(mydata, lat = ~lat, lon = ~lon) %>%
  add_markers( text = ~paste(lat, lon, Acc.,sep = "<br />"),
    color = ~Acc., symbol = I("square"), size = I(8), hoverinfo = "Acc."
  ) %>%
  colorbar(title = "Acc.") %>%
  layout(
    title = 'California Earthquake', geo = g)
```

***Data:***

@42-: "It would, however, be better practice to change all instances of data to a name that was not also an R-function name" (i.e. `mydata`).

```
read.table(text='lon          lat            Acc.

        -121.5897466    36.98443922 0.308722537
        -121.5776472    36.98446622 0.343560598
        -121.5657399    36.98449289 0.316238725
        -121.5528172    36.98452208 0.289579654
        -121.5397651    36.98455121 0.278277577
        -121.6022388    36.9957913  0.321904187
        -121.5897466    36.99578578 0.346187454
        -121.57767    36.99578046   0.323865427
        -121.5657514    36.99577518 0.296775313
        -121.5528643    36.99576944 0.281054324
        -121.5398582    36.99576372 0.270957516
        -121.6264404    37.00268339 0.3504049
        -121.614493     37.00268494 0.343426824
        -121.6022388    37.00268646 0.34803746
        -121.5897466    37.00268806 0.316975267
        -121.5776805    37.00268967 0.300399358
        -121.5657618    37.00269118 0.290519468
        -121.5528861    37.0026927  0.27529488
        -121.5399123    37.00269441 0.264715439
        -121.6264404    37.01301756 0.352218819
        -121.614493     37.01301354 0.342255779
        -121.6022388    37.01300933 0.333444018
        -121.5897466    37.01300512 0.315921346
        -121.5777013    37.01300115 0.302762624
        -121.5657723    37.01299709 0.291672835
        -121.5529293    37.01299261 0.266912813
        -121.614493     37.0204378  0.327864875
        -121.6022388    37.0204297  0.321358226
        -121.5897466    37.0204215  0.305797414
        -121.5777125    37.02041366 0.293992548
        -121.5657835    37.0204058  0.283948148
        -121.614493    37.0299123   0.313950088
        -121.6022388    37.02991694 0.303625182
        -121.5897466    37.02992166 0.291511686
        -121.5777299    37.02992617 0.282628812
        -121.5657949    37.02993068 0.271427682', header=TRUE, quote='"') -> 
    mydata  #named to have both code sections work and avoid a function name.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a solution using Google Maps (to use it you need an [api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key))?

```
library(googleway)

mapKey <- 'your_api_key'

google_map(key = mapKey) %>%
    add_heatmap(data = df, weight = "Acc.", option_radius = 0.02)
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly much better than my answer. +1 Edit: But it's not working for me. What's the reason?

Comment: @Masoud - not sure; do you have the latest release version of `googelway` ? and a valid API key?

Comment: @Masoud - I also called my data `df`

Comment: I just got an API and re-installed `googleway`. Idk, strange to me too.

Comment: @SymbolixAU , the same as Masoud, my api key does not work

Comment: @GulfChanter - it can take a few minutes to register

Comment: @SymbolixAU  The viewer stays blank yet, without any error. As I searched it is the problem of a few other researchers as well. I reinstalled the package several times.

Comment: @GulfChanter - the 'viewer' in RStudio?

Comment: @SymbolixAU  Yes, Do I have any other option?

Comment: @GulfChanter - can you press 'open in browswer' (might be called 'show in new window')?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Oh yeah!!, Now it works, Thanks! Can I add the legend or the numbers?

Comment: @GulfChanter - sadly not - I haven't got that part working yet - but it's on the development list. Out of interest, which version of RStudio are you running?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Version 1.0.136

Comment: @GulfChanter - ok - that may be causing the issue - I'm on 1.0.143 and had problems on older version too.

Comment: are you still maintaining the package or it's going orphan?

Comment: Hi @M-- yes, I'm still maintiaining it - do you see an issue with it?

Comment: @SymbolixAU it doesn't load google maps, I can post an issue tomorrow.